# Available Annyang voice recognition commands/ addCommands

Tags: javascript, voice, annyang

I'm working on a project in which i'd love to add talaters voice recognition Annyang. There are plenty of tutorials on how to use annyang and I've got it working on my website by following a tutorial (a pop up appears when I say hello to it). 
My question however is, are there any sites that describe the functions that you can pass to Annyang?

I understand that you can initiate Annyang using basically any voice command, but I'm looking for a comprehensive list of things you can actually execute with it.

I've looked everywhere and found nothing in terms of a list, or does one define and write these actions himself? If so, how do you go about this?

I looked at [this guys](https://github.com/evancohen/smart-mirror) implementation of it, he calls google maps when you ask for a map of a certain location, but I can't seem to figure out how it is implemented.

Am I that oblivious to the obvious or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

please go through the following link https://github.com/TalAter/annyang. and https://github.com/TalAter/annyang/tree/master/docs. you will get everything that you want to know about annyang and regarding the calling map may be he is doing something like below.

```
<script src="annyang.min.js"></script>

    if (annyang) {
      // Let's define a command.
      var commands = {
        'show me map of *location': function(location) { 
             //code for display map of argument location;
         }
      };

      // Add our commands to annyang
      annyang.addCommands(commands);

      // Start listening.
      annyang.start();
    }
```